# How to make an executable file?

Tags: python, windows, executable

Code for the background image of the GUI :

```
bg = PhotoImage(file='images/all_button.png')
lbl_bg = Label(root, image=bg)
lbl_bg.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1) 
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "finalbilling.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4061, in __init__
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4006, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "images/all_button.png": no such file or directory
[7912] Failed to execute script finalbilling
```

Comment: What's your os? even cannot run python file? cmd: python ./xxx.py

Comment: windows . its always shows error .Failed to execute script

Comment: This question shows absolutely no signs of any research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways in which you can convert it into an executable program.
But one such easy way is to use pyinstaller.
Firstly, download a module named pyinstaller by entering the below code into your console:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Then, open the folder in which you have kept your program with console.

In windows, you can go to the folder and press **shift** **key** and right click to get the option to open with powershell.

In Mac, you can head to the folder > Right click on the folder > Click New Terminal at folder.

Then in the terminal you can either:

```
pyinstaller (name of your file).py
```

In this one you will get many other files associated with your executable program.
**Don't try to delete those files else your executable file may get affected.**

Instead, try the below one to get only one executable file.

```
pyinstaller --onefile (name of file).py
```

You can get the executable program into **dist** folder of the folder you opened into console.

And then you can convert it to zip and send others.

If you are getting any type of errors like:
***No such file or directory [7912] Failed to execute script finalbilling***

Then there might be an issue with your script or while opening or importing any file an error occurred.
As the same happened with me and after resolving the issue in script it worked.

So, try to resolve the issue in script and then try the above steps it will definitely work.

Comment: I'm getting errors on images. No such file or directory .

Comment: Then I think you might have done some mistake in getting the location of the image you want to get.
Try to enter the absolute url of the image.

Comment: I already fixed it and the only error is when i open in the dist folder of the project and open the main application it pops up a cmd interface and nothing shows.

Comment: ohh okk I got the problem.
Maximum number of people face this problem.
If you are on windows then you can head on to the dist folder then hold shift and right click > select open with powershell > then type the name of your program(just the name without any extension) then press tab key > and press enter key.

It may take some time to execute your program

Comment: Thanks for the help. @Harsh Master. But i havent fix the problem because I have a lot of png image inside of folder of images

Comment: File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4061, in __init__
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4006, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "images/all_button.png": no such file or directory
[7820] Failed to execute script main

Comment: ohh okk.
did you fix the issue in the script but still the program is not executing and showing the above error?
If is it so then try deleting all the files that were created when you turned your program into an executable one like pycache, dist .....etc. delete all those 
now if you are using pycharm or visual studio any other then try to run the script in that code studio.
if it runs then try to create the executable program once again using pyinstaller.
This might work, if not let me know and tell the whole issue you are facing.

Comment: If the issue is occurring with the image location part then try to open your image with google chrome then get the url of the image from the address bar in google chrome.
And paste that url in the script instead of images/all_button.png and then convert to executable program

Comment: Harsh Master :) Thankyou for the help  . It fix the image directories error . can I ask if its possible to add also sqlite database to make it one executable file?

Comment: yaa sure but can you please elaborate.
I did not get your question in the comment?

Comment: I have created management system that can add ,delete, and edit records using sqlite database. currently my exe file has no errors while executing but it does not saving the records in exe file. so how can I add the database file to make it executable?

Comment: Sorry friend, I cannot answer this question.
But I tried to find something that can Help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=41&v=aylQNvVDPsg&feature=emb_logo
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229928/discussion-between-harsh-master-and-rocky-sotto).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the python script to a standalone executable with all its dependencies included using different python packages. One such package is pyinstaller which can be used to create executable for Windows, Mac OS X, or GNU/Linux. [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org)

Comment: Another such package is py2exe.  The trick is to make sure all of the needed elements have been copied into the archive/exe

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pyinstaller

pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

OR

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py # (will not work for console app)
```

`-w` means not to open CMD